# Do force-sensing resistors draw current?

Tags: current, resistors

I know that a resistor in a series and parallel circuit would draw a certain amount of current. However, would a force sensing resistor wired with a 10k pull-up like in a typical microcontroller application draw current with no force applied to it? And how about with force applied to it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to measure a resistance, the easiest way is to run some current through it...

Comment: Circuit, please

Comment: Any resistor is drawing current if has a voltage over it. Ohms Law, and everything...

Comment: You can't measure a device's resistance without running a current through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strain gauge is a resistor whose resistance alters when force is applied to it: -

[image]

It might alter its resistance by up to 10%. To measure that resistance change you can use a bridge (shown below) or feed a constant current into it or just use another resistor and a voltage supply: -

[image]

In every application of using a strain gauge, you have to have current flowing through the device in order to be able to read its value and hence compute how much strain/force is placed upon it.

So, usually in strain gauge applications the current is roughly the same whether mechanical load is applied or not.